# Syslog-ng broken/won't install after 16.04 > 18.04 dist upgrade

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, syslog

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM to 18.04. After the upgrade, syslog-ng was failing to start, so I purged it and tried reinstalling it. Every time I go to reinstall it, I get the "//Install failure" at the bottom of this post. The "//Status Output" is also listed as well for reference.

Things I've tried to resolve:
-Manually remove any .service locations that I found via a 'find / -name '*syslog-ng*';
-Ensuring there are no other syslog programs installed (i.e. rsyslog) via an 'apt purge sy[tab tab]';
-Deleted old kernel files via 'apt remove linux-[tab tab];
-Ensure there are no other programs listening on 514 via 'netstat -ptan | grep 514';
-Installed, purged, rebooted, and tried again. No success.

I'm kind of lost here. I'm by no means a linux guru, but I can navigate and program fairly well. I'm just not understanding what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

//Status Output

```
● syslog-ng.service - System [HOSTNAME] Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-10 20:04:59 EDT; 3min 27s ago
     Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
  Process: 14296 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F $SYSLOGNG_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14296 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Starting up... (Sat Aug 10 20:04:58 2019"

Aug 10 20:04:58 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Failed to start System [HOSTNAME] Daemon.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Stopped System [HOSTNAME] Daemon.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 10 20:04:59 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Failed to start System [HOSTNAME] Daemon.
```

---

//Install Failure

```
apt-get install syslog-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbson-1.0-0 libdbi1 libesmtp6 libhiredis0.13 libivykis0 libmongoc-1.0-0 libnet1 libprotobuf-c1
  librabbitmq4 libriemann-client0 libsnappy1v5 syslog-ng-core syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data
  syslog-ng-mod-amqp syslog-ng-mod-extra syslog-ng-mod-geoip syslog-ng-mod-getent
  syslog-ng-mod-graphite syslog-ng-mod-journal syslog-ng-mod-json syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs
  syslog-ng-mod-mongodb syslog-ng-mod-python syslog-ng-mod-redis syslog-ng-mod-riemann
  syslog-ng-mod-smtp syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser syslog-ng-mod-sql syslog-ng-mod-stardate
  syslog-ng-mod-stomp syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser
Suggested packages:
  rabbitmq-server graphite-web mongodb-server libdbd-mysql libdbd-pgsql libdbd-sqlite3 activemq
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbson-1.0-0 libdbi1 libesmtp6 libhiredis0.13 libivykis0 libmongoc-1.0-0 libnet1 libprotobuf-c1
  librabbitmq4 libriemann-client0 libsnappy1v5 syslog-ng syslog-ng-core
  syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data syslog-ng-mod-amqp syslog-ng-mod-extra syslog-ng-mod-geoip
  syslog-ng-mod-getent syslog-ng-mod-graphite syslog-ng-mod-journal syslog-ng-mod-json
  syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs syslog-ng-mod-mongodb syslog-ng-mod-python syslog-ng-mod-redis
  syslog-ng-mod-riemann syslog-ng-mod-smtp syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser syslog-ng-mod-sql
  syslog-ng-mod-stardate syslog-ng-mod-stomp syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser
0 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,342 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,547 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libbson-1.0-0.
(Reading database ... 82125 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libbson-1.0-0_1.9.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbson-1.0-0 (1.9.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbi1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libdbi1_0.9.0-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbi1:amd64 (0.9.0-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libesmtp6.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libesmtp6_1.0.6-4.3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libesmtp6 (1.0.6-4.3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhiredis0.13:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libhiredis0.13_0.13.3-2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsnappy1v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libsnappy1v5_1.1.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsnappy1v5:amd64 (1.1.7-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmongoc-1.0-0.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libmongoc-1.0-0_1.9.2+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmongoc-1.0-0 (1.9.2+dfsg-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnet1_1.1.6+dfsg-3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnet1:amd64 (1.1.6+dfsg-3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libprotobuf-c1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libprotobuf-c1_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libprotobuf-c1:amd64 (1.2.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librabbitmq4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-librabbitmq4_0.8.0-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librabbitmq4:amd64 (0.8.0-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libivykis0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libivykis0_0.42.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libivykis0:amd64 (0.42.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-journal.
Preparing to unpack .../10-syslog-ng-mod-journal_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-journal (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-core.
Preparing to unpack .../11-syslog-ng-core_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-core (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-json.
Preparing to unpack .../12-syslog-ng-mod-json_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-json (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../13-syslog-ng-mod-extra_3.13.2-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-extra (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser.
Preparing to unpack .../14-syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser.
Preparing to unpack .../15-syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libriemann-client0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libriemann-client0_1.9.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libriemann-client0:amd64 (1.9.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-sql.
Preparing to unpack .../17-syslog-ng-mod-sql_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-sql (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-mongodb.
Preparing to unpack .../18-syslog-ng-mod-mongodb_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-mongodb (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng.
Preparing to unpack .../19-syslog-ng_3.13.2-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data.
Preparing to unpack .../20-syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-amqp.
Preparing to unpack .../21-syslog-ng-mod-amqp_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-amqp (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-geoip.
Preparing to unpack .../22-syslog-ng-mod-geoip_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-geoip (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-getent.
Preparing to unpack .../23-syslog-ng-mod-getent_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-getent (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-graphite.
Preparing to unpack .../24-syslog-ng-mod-graphite_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-graphite (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs.
Preparing to unpack .../25-syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-python.
Preparing to unpack .../26-syslog-ng-mod-python_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-python (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-redis.
Preparing to unpack .../27-syslog-ng-mod-redis_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-redis (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-riemann.
Preparing to unpack .../28-syslog-ng-mod-riemann_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-riemann (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-smtp.
Preparing to unpack .../29-syslog-ng-mod-smtp_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-smtp (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser.
Preparing to unpack .../30-syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-stardate.
Preparing to unpack .../31-syslog-ng-mod-stardate_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-stardate (3.13.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package syslog-ng-mod-stomp.
Preparing to unpack .../32-syslog-ng-mod-stomp_3.13.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking syslog-ng-mod-stomp (3.13.2-3) ...
Setting up libhiredis0.13:amd64 (0.13.3-2.2) ...
Setting up libdbi1:amd64 (0.9.0-5) ...
Setting up libnet1:amd64 (1.1.6+dfsg-3.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Setting up libbson-1.0-0 (1.9.2-1) ...
Setting up libesmtp6 (1.0.6-4.3build1) ...
Setting up libprotobuf-c1:amd64 (1.2.1-2) ...
Setting up libivykis0:amd64 (0.42.2-1) ...
Setting up libriemann-client0:amd64 (1.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsnappy1v5:amd64 (1.1.7-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.25) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libmongoc-1.0-0 (1.9.2+dfsg-1build1) ...
Setting up librabbitmq4:amd64 (0.8.0-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up syslog-ng-mod-journal (3.13.2-3) ...
Setting up syslog-ng-core (3.13.2-3) ...
Job for syslog-ng.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status syslog-ng.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript syslog-ng, action "restart" failed.
● syslog-ng.service - System Logger Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-10 20:04:57 EDT; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
  Process: 14194 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F $SYSLOGNG_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14194 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Starting up... (Sat Aug 10 20:04:57 2019"
dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-core (--configure):
 installed syslog-ng-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-redis:
 syslog-ng-mod-redis depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-redis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-python:
 syslog-ng-mod-python depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs:
 syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-smtp:
 syslog-ng-mod-smtp depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-smtp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-geoip:
 syslog-ng-mod-geoip depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-geoip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-amqp:
 syslog-ng-mod-amqp depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-amqp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-sql:
 syslog-ng-mod-sql depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-sql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-json:
 syslog-ng-mod-json depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-getent:
 syslog-ng-mod-getent depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-getent (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser:
 syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng:
 syslog-ng depends on syslog-ng-core (>= 3.13.2); however:
  Package syslog-ng-core is not configured yet.
 syslog-ng depends on syslog-ng-mod-sql; however:
  Package syslog-ng-mod-sql is not configured yet.
 syslog-ng depends on syslog-ng-mod-json; however:
  Package syslog-ng-mod-json is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-stomp:
 syslog-ng-mod-stomp depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-stomp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-mongodb:
 syslog-ng-mod-mongodb depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-mongodb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-stardate:
 syslog-ng-mod-stardate depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-stardate (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data:
 syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-graphite:
 syslog-ng-mod-graphite depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-graphite (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-riemann:
 syslog-ng-mod-riemann depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-riemann (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser:
 syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser:
 syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser depends on syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0; however:
  Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.
  Package syslog-ng-core which provides syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of syslog-ng-mod-extra:
 syslog-ng-mod-extra depends on syslog-ng-mod-json (>= 3.13.2-3); however:
  Package syslog-ng-mod-json is not configured yet.
 syslog-ng-mod-extra depends on syslog-ng-mod-json (<< 3.13.2-3.1~); however:
  Package syslog-ng-mod-json is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-mod-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 syslog-ng-core
 syslog-ng-mod-redis
 syslog-ng-mod-python
 syslog-ng-mod-map-value-pairs
 syslog-ng-mod-smtp
 syslog-ng-mod-geoip
 syslog-ng-mod-amqp
 syslog-ng-mod-sql
 syslog-ng-mod-json
 syslog-ng-mod-getent
 syslog-ng-mod-snmptrapd-parser
 syslog-ng
 syslog-ng-mod-stomp
 syslog-ng-mod-mongodb
 syslog-ng-mod-stardate
 syslog-ng-mod-add-contextual-data
 syslog-ng-mod-graphite
 syslog-ng-mod-riemann
 syslog-ng-mod-tag-parser
 syslog-ng-mod-xml-parser
 syslog-ng-mod-extra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Adding sources list and journalctl output.

//Journalctl output

```
-- Unit syslog-ng.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit syslog-ng.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Stopped System Logger Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit syslog-ng.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit syslog-ng.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: syslog-ng.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 11 21:32:22 [HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Failed to start System Logger Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit syslog-ng.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit syslog-ng.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

//Sources

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http:// archive.canonical. com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http:// archive.canonical. com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http:// security.ubuntu. com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: I'd look further into the line that says `See "systemctl status syslog-ng.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: `egrep deb /etc/apt/sources.list` please.

Comment: @waltinator , there is no difference between 'systemctl status syslog-ng.service' and 'service syslog-ng status'; the output is identically the same. 'journalctl -xe' produces the result added to the original post

Comment: @nobody I added the source output to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sed -i s,//us.archive,//archive,g  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This converts the sources to main server.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

So apt draws the package new.

```
sudo apt update && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

No, error?  `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Then try again to install syslog-ng

If apt is complaining again about

> Package syslog-ng-abi-3.13-0 is not installed.

Install at first `sudo apt install syslog-ng-core`

the package that provides it.

Comment: Syslog-ng failed to install after steps. Cleaned, then tried just core.Got the below error. Systemctl/journal same errors.

Process: 595 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F $SYSLOGNG_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 595 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Starting up... (Tue Aug 13 01:11:46 2019"
dpkg: error processing package syslog-ng-core (--configure):
 installed syslog-ng-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 syslog-ng-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' `and `sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep rsyslog`

Comment: Nothing showed up in the dpkg grep at first, attempted the syslog-ng install to force the failure and then they all showed up. tried the purge and it didn't fix the problem still. Already thought of rsyslog being installed and confirmed it wasn't the night I upgraded to 18.04.